# Android SDK AVD manager crashes with "pure virtual method called"

Tags: android, sdk, android-emulator

Android ARM emulator crashes with following error:
[image]

OS: Windows 10

JAVA_HOME: 1.7.0_51

Dose anybody know whats the problem? Last time I used it, it worked ok. I've already tried another jdk and os restating without success.

Comment: any success in solving this? got the same. happens randomly.